# pandas explode functionality not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have data frame like this:

```
     title            price        weight
   0 Crloni Model145  $45,$50,$60  200gm,500gm,800gm
```

here $45 for 200gm, $50 for 500gm and $60 for 800 gm. My expected data frame will be look like this:

```
    title              price      weight
    0 Crloni Model145  $45        200gm 
    1 Crloni Model145  $50        500gm
    2 Crloni Model145  $60        800gm
```

But now I getting data frame like this

```
       title           price      weight
    0 Crloni Model145  $45        200gm 
    1 Crloni Model145  $45        500gm
    2 Crloni Model145  $45        800gm
    3 Crloni Model145  $50        200gm 
    4 Crloni Model145  $50        500gm
    5 Crloni Model145  $50        800gm
    6 Crloni Model145  $45        200gm 
    7 Crloni Model145  $45        500gm
    8 Crloni Model145  $45        800gm
    9 Crloni Model145  $60        200gm 
    10 Crloni Model145  $60        500gm
    11 Crloni Model145  $60        800gm
```

here is my code:

```
data['price']=data['price'].str.split(',')
data = data.explode('price')
data['weight']=data['weight'].str.split(',')
data = data.explode('weight')
```

updated question:

I applied **Bill the Lizard** solution. I am not getting any error but I am not seeing any price, weight in my csv when export the csv file.

```
data['price']=data['price'].str.split(',')
data['weight']=df['weight'].str.split(',')
data = data.set_index(['title']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()

data.to_csv('...mypath/data.csv')
```

see the pic:
[image]

here is **BENY** solution but I am getting `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

```
data['price'] = data['price'].str.split(',')
data['weight'] = data['weight'].str.split(',')
out = data.explode(['price','weight'])
data['description'] = data['description'].mask(data['description].shift() == data['description'])
```

**#update2**

**Bill the Lizard** solution worked but I am not understanding why **BENY** solution not working? why I am getting `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` this error when applying **BENY** solution

**update3**
few row of my original excel file

```
     category     title       price     weight             description
       Shirt    men-shirt    20,25,35    100gm,50gm,150gm   shirt description....   
      pant    men-pent    40,35,90    200gm,350gm,150gm   pant description....
```

Comment: Do you think `.explode` is deficient or your expectations are wrong? Can you make the DataFrame differently - do you have control of that?

Comment: @wwii I am start learning pandas and python. I searched on google and stack overflow for find solution but I didn't  find any solution. I have no idea how to solve this problems so  here  I am posted my problem. Still now I am trying to find solution

Comment: If **you** are making the DataFrame, it might be easier to *fix* during that step. You should include a minimal example of the data and the code you use to make the DataFrame.

Comment: @wwii can you please show me an example?

Comment: I think you'll get that error when you try to explode multiple columns that don't have the same number of values in their lists. Can you add the original values for `price` and `weight` for the few title shown in your Excel?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard see my updated question. I added few row of my original excel file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you have a Pandas version prior to 1.3.0, where multi-column [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) was added:**

Since the lists after splitting the strings have the same number of elements, you can apply `Series.explode` to the `price` and `weight` columns to the the expected output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['Crloni Model145'],
                   'price': ['$45,$50,$60'],
                   'weight': ['200gm,500gm,800gm']})

df['price']=df['price'].str.split(',')
df['weight']=df['weight'].str.split(',')

df = df.set_index(['title']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()

print(df)
```

I set the index to `title` because I don't want `explode` to be applied to that column, then I reset the index at the end so `title` becomes a regular column again.

Output:

```
             title price weight
0  Crloni Model145   $45  200gm
1  Crloni Model145   $50  500gm
2  Crloni Model145   $60  800gm
```

Comment: when export csv I am not seeing any price and weight. see the pic https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sbGDntZiG9SGVHtTkMCppApcRjnR4Zjt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @boyenec Please provide enough data in your example so we can reproduce this error.

Comment: sure. I am updating my questing

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: how to apply this function `data['image-link'] = data['image-link'].mask(data['image-link'].shift() == data['image-link'])` so I can prevent expanding image row ?

Comment: @boyenec Any columns that you don't want to expand should go in the index. `df.set_index(['title', 'image-link', ...])`

Comment: getting error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`  when I added extra column. Only working when I have only three column in my csv title, weight and price. But  I need to include others column in my csv

Answer (score 4):

Update your `pandas` and `explode` now can accept two columns

```
df['price'] = df['price'].str.split(',')
df['weight'] = df['weight'].str.split(',')
out = df.explode(['price','weight'])
```

Comment: That results in the error `ValueError: column must be a scalar` for me.

Comment: @colton update your pandas

Comment: good call, that is a much more elegant solution. I was on `1.2.4` and upgraded to `1.3.3`.

Comment: @ BENY getting `ValueError: column must be a scalar` and I upgraded my pandas

Comment: @boyenec update your panda

Comment: I upgrade pandas  to `1.3.3` and still now same error

Comment: @boyenec when you updated , you need restart your gui , and load the package again

Comment: @BENY now getting this error `ValueError: columns must have matching element counts`

Comment: @@BENY  I updated my question. please see